# windows server 2019 - restrict access to c drive for non admin users

Tags: administrator, windows-server-2019

How do I block C-drive access to all non admin users on server 2021? I have added all the users I want to block to a specific group - but not sure what to do next. Enabling it under “Prevent access to drives from My Computer" in group policy editor only blocks my own access, and that's not ideal. So a bit lost on how to proceed from here.

Comment: If you block viewing this drive how are they supposed to navigate their own user profile?  What are you trying to prevent by blocking users from viewing the drive in file explorer?

Comment: set all of their profiles to d drive.  so hopefully that wouldn't be a problem.  Read access no problem, but I prefer they didn't have any type of write access outside the d drive.

Comment: You are not going to be able to take away all write access to the system partition.